# 'inverting' rectangular matrix of a specific form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M$ be this matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

I would like to invert it, in the sense that I have a system of equations $y=Mx$ and I would like to get $x$ from $y$.

I can use the pseudoinverse $(M^t M)^{-1}M^t$, but I was wondering if in this case I could do better, due to the structure of the matrix. (in general it may be bigger but with the same typical structure).

Thanks.

Comment: In what sense would you like to do "better"? What makes one solution method better than the other? Ease of implementation, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy method of solution is to note that $M$ can be written as the block matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{\vec 1 & I}
$$
where $\vec 1$ is a column vector of $1$s and $I$ is the identity matrix.  We can write a vector in $\Bbb R^5$ in the form
$$
x = \pmatrix{x_1\\x'}
$$
where $x' = (x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^T \in \Bbb R^4$ and $x_1 \in \Bbb R$.  Block-matrix multiplication then yields
$$
Mx = \pmatrix{\vec 1 & I} \pmatrix{x_1\\x'} = \vec 1 x_1 + Ix' = x_1 \vec 1 + x'
$$
Thus, your system amounts to solving
$$
x_1 \vec 1 + x' = y
$$
for $x_1$ and $x'$ given $y$.  Perhaps from this point, you might see that there is always an "obvious" solution satisfying $x_1 = 0$.